# Return DbSet based on selection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core, dbset

I'm writing an ASP.NET Core MVC web app that is a tool for handling a parts database.  What I want is for the user to select a *Part* and then that will do some action, like delete that part from it's DB.  However, I want this to be a generic action used by all the parts.

I have a class hierarchy which is:

- Part

  - PartA
  - PartB

What I need is some method that I can call that will get the DbSet that my part belongs to.  This is an example of what I'm looking to do:

**Models**

```
public class Part
{
    public Nullable<int> ID { get; set; }
    public string Brand { get; set; }
}

public class PartA : Part
{
    public int Length { get; set; }
    public List<Image> Images { get; set; }
}

public class PartB : Part
{
    public int Durability { get; set; }
}

public class Image
{
    public Nullable<int> ID { get; set; }
    public string ImagePath { get; set; }
}
```

**PartsDbContext**

```
public class PartsDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<PartA> PartAs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<PartB> PartBs { get; set; }
}
```

**PartsController**

```
public IActionResult DeletePart (string partType, int id)
{
    var partSet = GetDbSet(partType);
    var part partSet.FirstOrDefault(e => e.ID == id);

    if (part != null)
    {
        partSet.Remove(part);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
}

//function to find and return DbSet of the selected type
private DbSet<Part> GetDbSet (string partType)
{
    switch (partType)
    {
        case "PartA":
            return _context.PartAs;
        case "PartB":
            return _context.PartBs;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Now obviously this doesn't work because the compiler will complain that:

> You can't convert type DbSet<PartA> to type DbSet<Part>

Anyone know how I might go about doing this?

Comment: Why do you have to switch by a query string? Why can't you use a different controller? Doesn't seem very REST.

Comment: I have only 2 different class of parts but each class could have 10+ specific parts that belong to it.  It doesn't seem like good practice to make 20+ controllers that all do basically the same exact thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really hacky, but sort of works.

```
public IActionResult DeletePart (string partType, int id)
{
    Type type = GetTypeOfPart(partType);
    var part = _context.Find(type, id);

    var entry = _context.Entry(part);
    entry.State = EntityState.Deleted;
    _context.SaveChanges();

}
```

However, you really should just use polymorphism and generic abstract Controllers.

EDIT You can also use Explicit Loading for this.

```
private void LoadRelatedImages(IPart part)
{
    _context.Entry(part)
         .Collection(p => p.Images)
         .Load();

}
```

Comment: This is pretty close, however I think I still need to get the DbSet because I'm not just worried about Deleting just the entry itself.  my entry contains a list of Image objects that I need to go thru and delete when the entry is deleted.  So I need to be able to use the line: `_context.DbSet.Include(e => e.Images).FirstOrDefault(e => e.ID == id);` or something else that will work.  Without this I believe your way doesn't allow me to cycle thru the Images for deletion from the database.

Comment: You can set the Cascade Delete options in your Database/Database Model and it will automagically delete the Images too.

Comment: OK first question is how would I go about setting Cascase Delete.  2nd question is: after trying you above answer I get an error with the `_context.Find`.  This is the error I get: 'The key value at position 0 of the call to 'DbSet<Tower>.Find' was of type 'int', which does not match the property type of 'Nullable<int>'.'  I've added more information about my models in the original post.

Comment: disregard my previous comment.  I figured out that the issue lied in my declaration of my ID Property and I've fixed that.  Now your code above works great!